# What's the role of "whatsoever" in this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality

> Meanwhile, Cathy has become a prostitute at the most respectable brothel in the city of Salinas. She renames herself "Kate" and embarks on a devious – and successful – plan to ingratiate herself with the owner, murder her, and inherit the business. She makes her new brothel infamous as a den of sexual sadism. She is not concerned that Adam Trask might ever look for her, and she has no feelings **whatsoever** about the children she abandoned.
>   ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/East_of_Eden_%28novel%29))

*Whatsoever* seems to be an adverb as in the case of Oxford ([I have no doubt whatsoever](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/whatsoever?q=whatsoever)); and the prepositional phrase, "about the children she abandoned," to modify *feelings* (or complement *feelings*). Is this right or do I have to see other ways?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Whatsoever* is an adverb used for emphasis, and it means "at all."

> I have no doubt whatsoever.

The sentence you quote means "she has no feelings at all."

As the NOAD says, *whatever* is also an archaic way to say *whatever*, but this is not the case in that sentence.

"About the children she abandoned" is a prepositional phrase describing the feelings she doesn't have. As in "I am thinking about you." *about* means *concerning*.